# Can "downstairs" in the phrase "From the street downstairs" be an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, phrase-meaning

> Vicki woke. Elizabeth was still sleeping, with her face to the wall. Her hair,
> flattened in the night, had formed matted curls which reminded Vicki
> against her will of what can be seen inside vacuum cleaners or the ripped
> seat of railway carriages. **From the street downstairs**, out the raised-eyebrow
> windows, rose a screeching of metal. Vicki slid out from under the
> pink quilt and went to the window, but the tram had launched itself again
> and was away, its little flag fluttering.

Does "street downstairs" mean: the rooms on the ground floor in a house. and "street downstairs" is another word for "ground floor"?

Or

Is "downstairs" here as an noun and "From the street downstairs" mean: from the downstairs that is towards street?

Can "downstairs" here be adverb?

Comment: "Street downstairs" isn't colloquial: downstairs is inside; the street is outside "From the street below" means the street. Otherwise there's "From downstairs" (any floor below yours), "From the floor below" or "From the ground/first/second/... floor."

Comment: The tram was going along the street past the house. It's a little odd to use 'downstairs' of something happening out of doors, but the noise (of the tram wheels scraping against the rails as it braked or went round a curve) was at ground level.

Comment: Please add a linked attribution. It sounds like an extract from a period novel. Nowadays one would expect 'from the street below'.  Lexico classes this usage as adverbial (perhaps assuming a deletion from 'street running below'), CGEL doubtless prepositional. I don't like either and stick at 'locative'.